# Why is the tkinter canvas being cleared sometimes but not all

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In the game that I am trying to make, one of the methods runs but one line of code does not seem to execute.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as m
import random as r
import math as ma

WOODEN="#DEB887"
PALE_COLOURS={"PALE_BLUE":"#CDF5F6",
"PALE_YELLOW":"#EFF9DA",
"PALE_RED":"#F9D8D6",
"PALE_GREEN":"#DDF0C7",
"PALE_PINK":"#D6CDEA",
"PALE_ORANGE":"#FFCD9B"}
PALE_GREY="#C3C3C3"
YELLOW="#FFFF00"
BLACK="#000000"

class Game(tk.Tk):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.geometry("920x210")
    self.configure(bg=WOODEN)
    self.resizable(False, False)
    self.title("Mancala")
    self.layout_info={"0":"P2","1":"P1"}
    self.turn="P2"
    self.P1pots={"Bank":Bank(self,"P1"),"Pits":[Pit(self,"P1",i) for i in range(1,9)]}
    self.P2pots={"Bank":Bank(self,"P2"),"Pits":[Pit(self,"P2",i) for i in range (1,9)]}
    self.distribute_counters()
    self.switch_turns()
    self.mainloop()

  def check_end(self):
    self.player1total=0
    self.player2total=0
    for item in self.P1pots["Pits"]:
      self.player1total+=len(item.counters)
    for item in self.P2pots["Pits"]:
      self.player2total+=len(item.counters)
    self.player1empty=self.player1total == 0
    self.player2empty=self.player2total == 0
    end = (self.player1empty) or (self.player2empty)
    if end:
      self.finish()

  def move_counters(self,sequence):
    global colours
    for x in range(len(colours)):
      for item in self.winfo_children():
        if item.grid_info()["row"] == sequence[x][0] and item.grid_info()["column"] == sequence[x][1]:
          last=item
          item.increment_counters()
    intermediate=self.layout_info[str(last.grid_info()["row"])]
    print(last.grid_info())
    print(last.counters)
    print(intermediate,self.turn)
    if len(last.counters) == 1 and intermediate == self.turn:
      if self.turn == "P1":
        self.P2pots["Pits"][last.grid_info()["column"]-1].clear_counters()
        self.P1pots["Bank"].increment_counters(len(colours))
      else:
        self.P1pots["Pits"][last.grid_info()["column"]-1].clear_counters()
        self.P2pots["Bank"].increment_counters(len(colours))
    elif last.grid_info()["column"] == 0 or last.grid_info()["column"] == 9:
      self.switch_turns()

  def finish(self):
    self.player1finaltotal=len(self.P1pots["Bank"].counters)
    self.player2finaltotal=len(self.P2pots["Bank"].counters)
    if self.player1empty:
      self.player2finaltotal+=self.player2total
      for item in self.P2pots["Pits"]:
        amount=len(item.counters)
        if amount != 0:
          item.clear_counters()
          self.P2pots["Bank"].increment_counters(amount)
    if self.player2empty:
      self.player1finaltotal+=self.player2total
      for item in self.P1pots["Pits"]:
        amount=len(item.counters)
        if amount != 0:
          item.clear_counters()
          self.P1pots["Bank"].increment_counters(amount)
    v=False
    if self.player1finaltotal > self.player2finaltotal:
      winner="Player 1"
    elif self.player2finaltotal > self.player1finaltotal:
      winner="Player 2"
    else:
      v=True
      m.showinfo("Endgame","It is a draw!")
    if not v:
      m.showinfo("Endgame",winner+" has won!")
    again=m.askyesno("Endgame","Do you want to play again?")
    if again:
      self.reset()
    else:
      self.destroy()
      quit()

  def reset(self):
    self.turn="P2"
    self.P1pots={"Bank":Bank(self,"P1"),"Pits":[Pit(self,"P1",i) for i in range(1,9)]}
    self.P2pots={"Bank":Bank(self,"P2"),"Pits":[Pit(self,"P2",i) for i in range (1,9)]}
    self.distribute_counters()
    self.switch_turns()
  
  def switch_turns(self):
    self.check_end()
    if self.turn == "P1":
      self.turn = "P2"
      for item in self.P2pots["Pits"]:
        if len(item.counters) != 0:
          item.add_events()
      for item in self.P1pots["Pits"]:
        item.remove_events()
    else:
      self.turn = "P1"
      for item in self.P1pots["Pits"]:
        if len(item.counters) != 0:
          item.add_events()
      for item in self.P2pots["Pits"]:
        item.remove_events()

  def distribute_counters(self):
    for item in self.P1pots["Pits"]:
      item.add_counters()
    for item in self.P2pots["Pits"]:
      item.add_counters()

class Cell(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self,master,height,BG):
    super().__init__(master=master,width=80,height=height,bg=BG,borderwidth=0)
    self.amount=0
    self.counters=[]
    self.start_canvas()
    self.redraw()
  
  def start_canvas(self):
    self.canv=tk.Canvas(self,width=80,height=80,bg=WOODEN,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
  
  def redraw(self):
    self.canv.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="NESW")


class Bank(Cell):

  def __init__(self,master,player):
    super().__init__(master,148,WOODEN)
    self.player=player
    self.counters=[]
    self.enlarge_canvas()
    self.add_pot()
    if player == "P1":
      self.grid(row=0,column=9,rowspan=2,pady=(7,10),padx=(10,15))
    else:
      self.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,pady=(10,7),padx=(15,10),sticky="NESW")

  def increment_counters(self,num=1):
    global colours
    for x in range(num):
      coord=(0,0)
      while self.invalid(coord):
        coord=(r.randint(10,70),r.randint(10,170))
      colour=colours.pop()
      self.counters.append(colour)
      c=(coord[0]-10,coord[1]-10,coord[0]+10,coord[1]+10)
      self.canv.create_oval(c,fill=colour,outline=BLACK)

  def invalid(self,coords):
    if coords[1] > 140:
      return ma.sqrt((coords[0]-40)**2+(coords[1]-140)**2) >= 30
    elif coords[1] < 40:
      return ma.sqrt((coords[0]-40)**2+(coords[1]-40)**2) >= 30
    else:
      return False
  
  def enlarge_canvas(self):
    self.canv.configure(height=180)

  def add_pot(self):
    self.p1=self.canv.create_arc((2,2,78,78),start=0,extent=180)
    self.p2=self.canv.create_arc((2,102,78,178),start=180,extent=180)
    self.p3=self.canv.create_line(2,40,78,40,fill=WOODEN)
    self.p4=self.canv.create_line(2,140,78,140,fill=WOODEN)
    self.p5=self.canv.create_line(2,40,2,140)
    self.p6=self.canv.create_line(78,40,78,140)
  

class Pit(Cell):

  def __init__(self,master,player,index):
    super().__init__(master,80,WOODEN)
    self.amount=6
    self.master=master
    self.counters=[]
    self.add_pot()
    if player == "P1":
      self.grid(row=1,column=index,pady=(7,12),padx=4,sticky="NESW")
    else:
      self.grid(row=0,column=9-index,pady=(12,7),padx=4,sticky="NESW")

  def increment_counters(self):
    global colours
    colour=colours.pop()
    if len(self.counters) == 6:
      self.canv.create_oval((30,30,50,50),outline=BLACK,fill=colour)
    else:
      dist=r.uniform(0,30)
      angle=r.uniform(0,2*ma.pi)
      y=dist*ma.sin(angle)
      x=dist*ma.cos(angle)
      coords=(x+50,y+50,x+30,y+30)
      self.canv.create_oval(coords,outline=BLACK,fill=colour)
    self.counters.append(colour)
  
  def chosen(self,event):
    self.clear_counters()
    self.determine_sequence()
    self.master.switch_turns()
  
  def determine_sequence(self):
    if self.grid_info()["row"] == 0:
      orderlist=[(0,x) for x in range(self.grid_info()["column"]-1,0,-1)]+[(0,0)]+[(1,x) for x in range(1,9)]
      orderlist+=orderlist+orderlist+orderlist
      self.master.move_counters(orderlist)
    else:
      orderlist=[(1,x) for x in range(self.grid_info()["column"]+1,9)]+[(0,9)]+[(0,x) for x in range(8,0,-1)]
      orderlist+=orderlist+orderlist+orderlist
      self.master.move_counters(orderlist)
  
  def clear_counters(self):
    global colours
    colours=self.counters
    print("A")
    self.canv.delete("all")
    print("B")
    self.p1=self.canv.create_oval(1,1,79,79)
    self.counters=[]

  def add_events(self):
    self.canv.bind("<Enter>",lambda e: self.canv.itemconfig(self.p1,outline=YELLOW))
    self.canv.bind("<Leave>",lambda e: self.canv.itemconfig(self.p1,outline=BLACK))
    self.canv.bind("<Button-1>",self.chosen)

  def remove_events(self):
    self.canv.unbind("<Enter>")
    self.canv.unbind("<Leave>")
    self.canv.unbind("<Button-1>")
  
  def add_pot(self):
    self.p1=self.canv.create_oval(1,1,79,79)

  def add_counters(self):
    coords=[(43,7,63,27),(18,7,38,27),(43,53,63,73),(18,53,38,73),(4,30,24,50),(76,50,56,30)]
    for z in range(6):
      colour=PALE_COLOURS[list(PALE_COLOURS)[z]]
      self.counters.append(colour)
      self.canv.create_oval(coords[z],outline=BLACK,fill=colour)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  window = Game()
```

In the game (called Mancala), players take it in turns to choose cells and the counters are taken out and put in the cells to the right or left of them (depending on which player), into their 'bank' then into the other player's pots. To do this, the clear_counters() method in the Pit() class is executed which clears the counters from that cell using self.canv.delete("all") and stores the information about their colours in a list called colours. This is then used to place them in the cells during the turn.
There is a rule in the game where if a player picks a cell whose last counter is placed in an empty box on their side, they take the counters in the cell opposite the one they placed the last counter in and put them in their 'bank'. When this happens, the clear_counters() method is called again and, using the print("A") and print("B") statements, I can see that the method is being run but the canvas does not seem to be being cleared in the special rule scenario.
There is another rule where you get another go if the last counter you placed is in your pot but that is not relevant but may be convenient to know.
I appreciate my explanation is probably horrible but hopefully, by testing the game, you can see how it works.
I am using Replit Online IDE so the geometry may be different if you test it.
Additionally, I know you are only supposed to put a reproducible example of the problem but basically the entire code is needed as the game is basically finished and the line self.canv.delete("all") runs sometimes but not others.
To clarify the problem, where the possible moves are from columns 2 to 9, to reach the scenario, choose column 6, 2, 7, 8 and then column 6 again should move one counter to the next empty space. The rule is that the counters in the pot above should be cleared and put in the 'bank' of player 1. They are being put in the bank correctly but the pot is not being cleared.

Comment: Player1 won. I don't see the canvas being clear. Do u mean gui being clear or not. When the player1 has won, all oval  are empty. Why all time player1 not even player 2

Comment: I merely see all balls on left and right side.

Comment: Hopefully I've clarified

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood your explanation right. When I follow your instructions to reach the scenario. Upon clicking column 6, the second player's column 4 pot is cleared.

This makes me think that you need to access the pots in reverse.

Change lines 59 and 62 from

```
self.P2pots["Pits"][last.grid_info()["column"]-1].clear_counters()
```

to

```
self.P2pots["Pits"][-last.grid_info()["column"]].clear_counters()
```

Comment: Player2 has won. Play again then I got an error...line 206, in increment_counters
    colour=colours.pop()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: pop from empty list